# applying function to all name-value pairs of a list

Tags: r

Suppose that I have some list like this

```
somelist <- list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 4, d = 8)
```

and some function like this

```
somefunction <- function (key, value) paste(replicate(value, key), collapse = "")
```

I would like to apply `somefunction` to all of `somelist`'s name/value pairs.

One way to do it:

```
sapply(names(somelist), function (name) somefunction(name, somelist[[name]]),
       USE.NAMES = FALSE)
## [1] "a"        "bb"       "cccc"     "dddddddd"
```

I could encapsulate this functionality like this:

```
myapply <- function (somelist, somefunction, ...) {
    sapply(names(somelist),
           function (name) somefunction(name, somelist[[name]]),
           ...)
}
```

So,

```
myapply(somelist, somefunction, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
## [1] "a"        "bb"       "cccc"     "dddddddd"
```

---

My question: Does something like `myapply` (above) already exist in `R`?

Comment: `mapply` and its wrapper `Map` are the multi-argument versions of `lapply`. Try `mapply(somefunction,names(somelist),somelist)`

Comment: I'd note also that your function mainly does what the new R function `strrep` does: `strrep(names(somelist),somelist)`.